# How do you map a 3d matrix to color values in a 3d scatter plot using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a `10x10x10` numpy matrix that I'm trying to visualize in 3d:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
M = np.random.rand(10, 10, 10)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
counter = range(10)
ax.scatter(counter, counter, counter, c=??)
```

I would like a 3d plot where the darkness at location `i,j,k` is given by `M[i,j,k]`. How exactly am I suppose to pass `M` to `scatter()` so that it does this correctly? It seems to want a 2d array, but I don't understand how that would work in this case.

Comment: The scatter you have is composed of 10 points. How would you like the 1000 points of M distributed to the 10 points of the scatter?

Answer (score 10):

The scatter needs the same number of points than the color array `c`. So for 1000 colors you need 1000 points.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
M = np.random.rand(10, 10, 10)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
counter = range(10)
x,y,z = np.meshgrid(counter, counter, counter)
ax.scatter(x,y,z, c=M.flat)


plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is already clearing some things up. But I'm still confused by `scatter` does with `M`. For example, if I switch you code to `M = np.random.rand(11, 10, 10)` and leave everything else as is, I get the error: "ValueError: Color array must be two-dimensional". But in your working example it's three-dimensional....

Comment: Oh that's probably simply because someone forgot to change the error message to the 3d case. I would interprete this as reading "color array's shape does not match input arrays' shape" or similar. It's always the same: If you have 1000 points, you need 1000 colors, if you have 1100 colors you need 1100 points, one point per color.

Comment: I had to use M = np.random.rand(1000)

Comment: you have to change `ax.scatter(x,y,z, c=M)` with `ax.scatter(x,y,z, c=M.ravel())`

Comment: @D_Serg Yes, indeed, we changed that last version.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
scatter3D(xs, ys, zs=0, zdir='z', s=20, c=None, depthshade=True, *args, **kwargs)
```

But c != None

https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html